# Nginx - 502 bad gateway from changing user in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

If I change the user parameter in nginx.conf from:

```
user www-data
```

to

```
user www www
```

*www* is a user and *www* is also a group (existing already)

it says **502 bad gateway**

How would I successfully be able to run nginx as the *www* user.

Cheers

Comment: Show full config. Did you restart nginx? Do you proxy request to backend? Which one and how is it configured?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the command

> chown -R www:www "Document Root"

This will ensure that all of your web files are owned by that user and group meaning nginx can access them.

If yopu have any .php files in your document root you will also have to go to your php fpm config file and change the lines

```
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
```

If you are running centos go to:

> /etc/php.fpm.d

where you will find the www.conf file to find those settings.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should also change user in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`(Ubuntu 16.10) file

```
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
```

This error appears when you change nginx process user without changing this params in php-fpm.

After that restart php-fpm process:

```
service php7.0-fpm restart (for php 7.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error may be caused if your are passing the request to fastcgi(php), to do this nginx has to access the file `/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` (for php7.4), I checked the logs and found out that it was denied the permission to access this file.

I ran this command:

```
> sudo chown ubuntu /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

and then it worked correctly.